# Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only

Tags: python, django, authentication, registration

My username field that I have on my form using django user_auth displays : "Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only" right next to it as shown in the image below.  Anyone has any idea how to hide it or why does it appear on the form?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

That text is there because the [`help_text` for the form field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/fields/#help-text) has been set to that text. Also see the [*Creating forms from models* documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/) on other ways the `help_text` value could have been set; it could have been set on the model field, for example.

Presumably it is there because there is a the field has a [form validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/validation/) attached to it that only passes if the username entered matches those rules.

If you are building your form from a model, you can override *just* this field by setting `help_texts` on the form `Meta` class:

```
class YourForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        help_texts = {
            'username': None,
        }
```

The attribute is a mapping from field id to text; setting it to `None` will disable the text altogether. Take into account that any validators will still be in place however!

You could also replace the whole field:

```
class YourForm(ModelForm):
    username = forms.RegexField(
        label='Username', 
        max_length=30,
        regex=r'^[\w-]+$',
        error_message='This value must contain only letters, numbers, hyphens and underscores.')

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
```

But do read the note section of the [*Overriding default fields* section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/#s-overriding-the-default-fields) of the model forms documentation.

Comment: Ok but I didnt add the help text. Is there any way I can hide it in the model using only the field name?

Comment: You haven't told us *anything* about what you are doing, how you created the form for example. All I can do in that situation is point you to the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by adding this line in my form.

```
username = forms.CharField(help_text=False)
```

Thank you.

Comment: What if i am using model form